# How to sort array in typescript by value

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

How can I order this array of Objects by isActive value "True"?

```
[{src: "SafeUrlImpl", id: "10047", filename: "Verify Event screenshot .jpg", fileType: "1", isActive: false},
 {src: "SafeUrlImpl", id: "1006", filename: "Verify Event screenshot .jpg", fileType: "1", isActive: true},
 {src: "SafeUrlImpl", id: "10045", filename: "Verify Event screenshot .jpg", fileType: "1", isActive: false},
 {src: "SafeUrlImpl", id: "10045", filename: "Verify Event screenshot .jpg", fileType: "1", isActive: false}]
```

I need an output based on isActive value True as below

```
 [{src: "SafeUrlImpl", id: "1006", filename: "Verify Event screenshot .jpg", fileType: "1", isActive: true},
 {src: "SafeUrlImpl", id: "10047", filename: "Verify Event screenshot .jpg", fileType: "1", isActive: false},
 {src: "SafeUrlImpl", id: "10045", filename: "Verify Event screenshot .jpg", fileType: "1", isActive: false},
 {src: "SafeUrlImpl", id: "10045", filename: "Verify Event screenshot .jpg", fileType: "1", isActive: false}]
```

Comment: Try to use the sort function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.sort()` method.

```
const result = data.sort((a,b) => +b.isActive - +a.isActive);
```

Comment: If you see a comment on a question starting with "Does this answer your question?" followed by a link, follow the link and see if the answers to the linked question answer the question. If so, please refrain from answering the question, as it spreads the answers and questions out, making it harder for people to find.